# Jquery Selectable TD Return

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that is connected to Jquery selectable, and Im trying to get it to grab the value of the selected table item and put it in a text box. I keep getting

[object object] as the table value

here is the script

```
<script>
$( "#drilldowntable" ).selectable(
    { filter:"td",
      stop: function(){
        $(".ui-selected", this).each(function(){
          var index = $("#drilldowntable td").val(this);
       $("#graphinfo").val(index);
        }
        )}
        });

        </script>
```

any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this? Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/JS45n/)**</kbd>

```
$("#drilldowntable").selectable({
  filter: "td",
  selected: function() {
     $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
       $("#graphinfo").val($(this).text());
     });
  }
});
```

by the way to retrieve `td` content you must use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) only inputs have values.